# Extracting size_t template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I was wondering what is the best way to get access to a size_t template parameter, so that I can pass it along to another templated class (so not via a method call).  For instance if I have the classes,

```
template<typename T, size_t D> class Point;
template<typename T> class Line;

template<typename T, size_t D>
class Shape
{
  public:
   virtual size_t dims() const = 0;
   virtual bool intersects(Point<T,D> p) const  = 0;
   virtual bool intersects(Line<Point<T,D>> l) const = 0;
}

template<typename T, size_t D>
class Point : Shape<T,D>
{
  public:
   typedef T type;
   size_t dims() const {return D;}
   type val(size_t d) {return vals[d];}
   bool intersects(Point<T,D> p)
   {
     for(size_t d=0; d<D; ++d) if(p.vals[d] != vals[d]) return false;
     return true;
   }     

   bool intersects(Line<Point<T,D>> l)
   {
     return l.intersects(*this);
   }  

  protected:
   type vals[D];
};

// How do I get D???
template<typename Point_t>
class Line : public Shape<typename Point_t::type,??>
{
  public:
   typedef typename Point_t::type type;
   size_t dims() const {return point.dims();}

   bool intersects(Point<type,??> p) {/*stuff*/}      
   bool intersects(Line<Point_t> l) {/*stuff*/}

  private:
   Point_t point;
   type slope;
};
```

I want to ensure the intersects method within Line ONLY works for a Line intersecting a point of the same dimensions (prevent 3D line intersecting a 2D point).  I thought about having Line take the same parameters as Point, but then the compiler wouldn't catch errors such as intersecting a Cartesian defined Line with a Spherically defined Point (since both are `Point<double,3>`).  With how I have it above, I can define cartesian and spherical classes to avoid this issue.

```
 template<typename T, size_t D> class Cartesian : public Point<T,D>{/*stuff*/}
 template<typename T> class Spherical : public Point<T,3> {/*stuff*/}

 Line<Cartesian<double,3>> Line;
 Cartesian<double,3> C3Point;
 Cartesian<double,2> C2Point;
 Spherical<double> SPoint;
 Line.intersects(C3Point); // ok
 Line.intersects(C2Point); // compiler error
 Line.intersects(SPoint); // compiler error
```

edit:
what I currently do is define the Line class as

```
template<typename Point_t, size_t D>
class Line : public Shape<typename Point_t::type,D>
{/*stuff*/}
```

which works, but contains redundant info...

```
 Line<Cartesian<double,3>,3> Line;
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++11, you may turn

```
size_t dims() const {return D;}
```

into

```
static constexpr size_t dims() {return D;}
```

And so

```
template<typename Point_t>
class Line : public Shape<typename Point_t::type, Point_t::dims()> {..};
```

Comment: The second one doesn't handle OP's example.

Comment: @T.C.: Just saw that.

Comment: Don't you need `typename` before `Point_t::type` ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: Indeed. Focused on `dims` part.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.  My actual code is more complicated than the example (which is why I think it was harder for me to see the solution), but this basic method worked.  I restructured my classes as below,

```
template<typename T> class Line;

template<typename T, size_t D>
class Point
{
  public:
   typedef T type;
   size_t dims() const {return D;}
   type val(size_t d) {return vals[d];}
   bool intersects(Point<T,D> p)
   {
     for(size_t d=0; d<D; ++d) if(p.vals[d] != vals[d]) return false;
     return true;
   }     

   bool intersects(Line<Point<T,D>> l)
   {
     return l.intersects(*this);
   }  

  protected:
   type vals[D];
};

template<typename T>
class Shape
{
  public:
   typedef T Point_t;
   virtual size_t dims() const = 0;
   virtual bool intersects(Point_t p) const  = 0;
   virtual bool intersects(Line<Point_t> l) const = 0;
}

template<typename Point_t>
class Line : public Shape<Point_t>
{
  public:
   typedef typename Point_t::type type;
   size_t dims() const {return point.dims();}

   bool intersects(Point_t p) {/*stuff*/}      
   bool intersects(Line<Point_t> l) {/*stuff*/}

  private:
   Point_t point;
   type slope;
};
```

Now the following works as expected,

```
 template<typename T, size_t D> class Cartesian : public Point<T,D>{/*stuff*/}
 typedef Cartesian<double,3> Cartesian3D;
 typedef Cartesian<double,2> Cartesian2D;
 template<typename T> class Spherical : public Point<T,3> {/*stuff*/}

 Line<Cartesian3D> Line;
 Cartesian3D CPoint3D;
 Cartesian2D CPoint2D;
 Spherical<double> SPoint;
 Line.intersects(C3Point); // ok
 Line.intersects(C2Point); // compiler error
 Line.intersects(SPoint); // compiler error
```

Basically, I don't consider Point to be a Shape.  If I do that, I don't need the Shape class to know D, and everything Derived from Shape will contain a Point_t from which I can get the dimensions.  I just need to remember to explicitly put intersection methods for each Class derived from Shape into the Point class.